# How to Reduce Speech Feature Dimensions?

Tags: speech-recognition, mfcc

I have been experimenting with speaker independent automatic speech recognition.  At this point, I understand that the signal is typically segmented into overlapping frames and MFCCs are extracted as features for each frame.

A lot of the texts I read talk about reducing the dimensionality of the features using (for example) Linear Discriminant Analysis or Primary Component Analysis.  While I think I understand the concepts involved in reducing dimensions in the abstract, I am not understanding how this feature reduction is supposed to be applied to the MFCC vectors.

I am interested primarily because several texts seem to suggest that reducing the dimensionality produces less variant features, which make recognizing patterns easier.  As a bonus, there is also less computational overhead.

Is the dimension reduction supposed to be applied on a per-frame basis?  For something like LDA, don't you need to know what class the data belongs to?

Thanks,
Carl

Comment: See nonnegative matrix factorisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one feature vector per frame. The collection of feature vectors for all the frames in the training data form a matrix. Since this is training data, you know the true class for each frame. Use this matrix and the training data labels to build your LDA matrix. Alternatively, just use this matrix (without the labels) to find the PCA matrix.

Now you use this matrix to reduce the dimensionality of the feature vector for each frame in your test data when you're doing the speech recognition.

PCA doesn't produce less variant features. I think what you meant to say was that the features are less correlated with each other. This is called whitening and it can help some classifiers better learn from the training data.

Comment: The PCA explanation makes sense to me.  However I am not clear how one might determine what the classes should be for LDA.  What are the labels supposed to represent in the training data?  It is my understanding that the number of classes ought to be less than the number of dimensions.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to predict with your features?

Comment: I'd like to be able train a database of template phonemes and the recognize the phonemes from an untrained speech sample.  I use DTW to compare the distance between each segment in the untrained signal against each template and emit the closest.

Comment: If you are trying to recognize phonemes then phonemes will be your feature for LDA

Comment: There are 13 MFCCs (39 if you take deltas and delta-deltas).  This is fewer than the number of phonemes in English.  So if the number of classes is so big, does LDA help?  Am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: I see what you mean. I don't know a whole lot about speech recognition but I think in professional-grade systems the MFCCs are combined with other features such as pitch features, probability of voicing, and neural network based features. Maybe that's why the dimensionality reduction is so important for them because they have more features.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it did help me understand how PCA could be applied to the process.  I am still interested in a concrete example of how someone applied LDA.  I am interested to know if there are other features I am not really considering.